# Xlabs GridView doesn't work correctly with any Layouts on Android

Tags: c#, android, gridview, xamarin.forms, xlabs

Xlabs `GridView` on android doesn't show the Relative or stack layouts. But its work fine on `iOS`. If i set in "cell.View" `img` its work fine on both platforms, but if i set any layout in "cell.View" `GridView` displays only background color on Android, on `iOS` all good, anybody can help?

```
GridImage.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => {
var rel = new RelativeLayout ();

            var img = new Image () {
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
            };
            img.SetBinding (Image.SourceProperty, ".", converter: new FilterToImageSourceConverter ());
            var label = new Label () {
                TextColor = Color.White,
                FontSize = 20,
                XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                YAlign = TextAlignment.Center
            };
            label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, ".", converter: new FilterToLabelTextConverter ());

            label.GestureRecognizers.Add (new TapGestureRecognizer ((sender, e) => {
                ItemClicked ();
            }));

            rel.Children.Add (img,
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => {
                    return 0;
                }),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => {
                    return 0;
                }),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => {
                    return parent.Width;
                }),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => {
                    return parent.Height;
                })
            );

            rel.Children.Add (label,
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => {
                    return 0;
                }),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => {
                    return 0;
                }),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => {
                    return parent.Width;
                }),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => {
                    return parent.Height;
                })
            );
            var cell = new ViewCell ();
            cell.View = rel;
            return cell;
        });
```